# Stack Trace with Line Numbers nLog

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nlog

I've recently been working with nLog to add additional logging to one of our web applications.  All is well except we'd like to capture filenames and line numbers in our test environment to aid in debugging.  I thought I had the answer with:`layout="${stacktrace:format=raw}"` but while that looks like it may work in some cases, it did not in my test.  It produced the following output:

```
InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive at offset 177 in file:line:column <filename unknown>:0:0
OnActionExecuting at offset 52 in file:line:column <filename unknown>:0:0
CheckAccess at offset 1514 in file:line:column <filename unknown>:0:0
```

Notice that the filename is "unknown" and the line and column numbers are 0.

I double checked that I was in debug mode and when I inspect the exception, I can see the standard .NET stack trace and it has filenames and line numbers:

```
at [REDACTED].CheckAccess(ActionExecutingContext& filterContext) in [REDACTED]\\attribute.cs:line 92
```

Here is my nLog.config file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd NLog.xsd"
      autoReload="true"
      throwExceptions="true"
      internalLogLevel="Off" internalLogFile="c:\temp\nlog-internal.log">

    <variable name="InstanceURL" value="localhost"/>

<targets>
    <target 
        name="MainLog" 
        xsi:type="Database" 
        connectionStringName="docsdb"
        commandText="insert into ErrorLog(Message,StackTrace,InnerExceptionMessage,DateOccurred,UserName, InstanceURL) values( @message, @stacktrace, @log_exception,@time_stamp,@user_name,@instance_url);"
    >
        <parameter name="@time_stamp" layout="${date:format=yyyy-MM-ddTHH\:mm\:ss.fff}"/>
        <parameter name="@message" layout="${message}"/>
        <parameter name="@user_name" layout="${windows-identity:domain=true}"/>
        <parameter name="@log_exception" layout="${exception:format=ToString}"/>
        <parameter name="@stacktrace" layout="${stacktrace:format=raw}"/>
        <parameter name="@instance_url" layout="${var:InstanceURL}"/>
    </target>
</targets>

  <rules>
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="MainLog" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

My questions are:
1) Am I configuring the stack trace correctly?
2) Is there a way to log a ".Net style" stack trace?  I prefer the more verbose .NET stack trace.

**EDIT:**
This has nothing to do with missing PDB files.  PDBs are included and if I manually log (outside of nlog) an exception, the stack trace includes the filename and line numbers.  I'm trying to figure out what I need to do to get nLog to include them.  Thanks.

Comment: _"filename is "unknown" and the line and column numbers are 0"_ - then you're missing the PDBs.

Comment: Please read my entire post.  The filenames and line numbers ARE there when looking at the exception.  They just don't show up in nLog.  The PDB is included and was built with symbols included.

Comment: the exception stacktrace and non-exception stacktrace are different. - `${exception:format=stacktrace}` should work. The correct way to test it, is to print  `Environment.StackTrace` . So it's very likely this question is indeed a duplicate.